# Find probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a task to solve: Ω: {1, 2, 3}, E = 2.1, D = 0.89, I need to find the probabilities.

It seems like this question is possible to solve vie linear equations system. But I've come up only with this one:

1. p1 + 4 * p2 + 9 * p3 = 5.3 (dispersion)
2. p1 + 2 * p2 + 3 * p3 = 2.1 (expected value)
3. p1 + p2 + p3 = 1 (probabilities sum)

And it doesn't produce sane result.

Can anyone help with understanding where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I do not overlook something, but I do not see the error. I came out:

$p_1 = 0.4, p_2 = 0.1, p_3 = 0.5$

Comment: Yes, today I've found a mistake in my calculations and come up with the same result, which seems to be correct.